# How to pass states between two components react?

Tags: reactjs

I need the Cart component in Navbar.js to open whenever i click on the "Add To Cart" button in the CartButton component which is found in multiple pages.

here is the code and what i tried so far but it doesn't work:

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleCart = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
                <HiOutlineShoppingBag onClick={() => toggleCart(open)} /> ----> function to have the cart component open when i click on the shopping bag icon (this works perfectly)
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      {open && <Cart />} --------> Opens the cart component.
    </header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

CartButton.js

```
const CartButton = ({ open, setOpen }) => {

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setOpen(open)} ----> need this to open the <Cart /> component in Navbar.js
      <HiOutlineShoppingBag />
      <p className="text-bold">Add To Cart</p>
    </button>
  );
};

export default CartButton;
```

i get the error "setOpen" is not a function.. how do i fix it?

Comment: Firsly the 'Cart' component is not CartButton. 2nd you need to supply the state from the parent as a prop to the CartButton like this <CartButton open={open} />.

Answer (score 0):

pls, show the place you call CartButton component and check if you sending it the props, you try to use (open, setOpen)

should be smth like this

```
<CartButton open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
```

also I can't understand, you try to export Navbar as default, but show the HeaderComponent, it wouldn't work I guess.

Comment: sorry about the the HeaderComponent thing i had edited it to "Navbar.js" to make it easier to understand in the question, i fixed it now :). Sorry i am bad at explaining cause english isn't my first language, but do you when you're shopping online and you click on "add to cart" and the cart ui opens automatically to show the product you just added.. that's what i'm trying to do here...

Comment: okay:) then let's check in which component you render a CartButton? to change state of another component you need to pass props, which you call in the component. if you didn't not pass it, you will get an error like you describe

Comment: Feels more like an extended comment than an answer here

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `<HiOutlineShoppingBag />` is also a component, correct?

You need to pass `setOpen` state as props into it

```
<header>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <HiOutlineShoppingBag setOpen={setOpen}/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  {open && <Cart />} --------> Opens the cart component.
</header>
```

And then inside the `HiOutlineShoppingBag` component you run the function

```
export function HiOutlineShoppingBag({ setOpen }) {
  return (
   <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
    submit 
   </button>
 )}
```

this way you will be able to change the state value in the NavBar component.

But if your project is big or you need a more solid solution, I advise you to use React's `useContext` hook. It can make the variables and functions created within it available globally in your project

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext